# Problema en C++ Al momento de mostrar los datos del fichero guardado

Tags: c++, lista, punteros, archivo

espero que esten bien, mi problema radica en que tengo una funcion para agregarle un vehiculo a una persona a traves de un puntero, al momento de agregarlo todo marcha bien, y le doy a la opcion de mostrar en pantalla la informacion del usuario y del vehiculo que se le ha agregado, hasta alli todo va bien, pero al cerrar el programa y volverlo a abrir, al momento de darle nuevamente a mostrar informacion del usuario, cuando llega a la seccion del vehiculo el programa estalla, alguien sabe por que pasa esto?, muchas gracias de antemano, les adjunto el codigo a continuacion

```
struct vehiculo{
char placa[8];
char marca[15];
char modelo[15];
int year;
char color[10];
struct infraccion *misInfracciones;
struct vehiculo *sigVehiculo;};

struct personas{
int cedula;
char nombre[20];
int fechaDeNacimiento;
char sexo;
int edad;
char direccion[40];
struct vehiculo *misVehiculos;};

void mostrarVehiculos(struct vehiculo *v){
vehiculo *veh = v;
while(veh){
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Placa del Vehiculo: %s\n", veh->placa);
    printf("Marca del Vehiculo: %s\n", veh->marca);
    printf("Modelo del Vehiculo: %s\n", veh->modelo);
    printf("Año del Vehiculo: %i\n", veh->year);
    printf("Placa del Vehiculo: %s\n", veh->color); 
    printf("----------------------------------------");
    veh = veh->sigVehiculo;
}}

void mostrarInfo(struct personas p){//Mostramos la informacion del usuario
printf("----------------------------\n");
printf("Nombre: %s\n", p.nombre);
printf("Cedula: %i\n", p.cedula);
printf("Direccion: %s\n", p.direccion);
printf("Fecha De Nacimiento: %i\n", p.fechaDeNacimiento);
printf("Sexo: %c\n", p.sexo);
if(p.misVehiculos == NULL){
    printf("Esta persona no posee vehiculos registrados\n");
}else{
    mostrarVehiculos(p.misVehiculos);
}
printf("----------------------------\n");}

void mostrarUsers(){
FILE *pFile;
personas p;
if((pFile = fopen("Registro.txt", "r"))==NULL){
    printf("No existe ningun Fichero creado");
    system("pause");
}else{
    fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, pFile);
    while(!feof(pFile)){
        mostrarInfo(p);
        fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, pFile);
    }
}
fclose(pFile);}

void aggUser(){
FILE *pFile;
personas p;
if(comprobarSiExisteFichero == 0){
    pFile = fopen("Registro.txt", "w");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el Nombre del usuario\n");
    gets(p.nombre);fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el numero de cedula de %s\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%i", &p.cedula); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la direccion donde reside %s\n", p.nombre);
    gets(p.direccion); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento de %s\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%i", &p.fechaDeNacimiento); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el sexo de %s (M/F)\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%i", &p.sexo); fflush(stdin);
    p.misVehiculos = NULL;
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}else{
    pFile = fopen("Registro.txt","a");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el Nombre del usuario\n");
    gets(p.nombre);fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el numero de cedula de %s\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%i", &p.cedula); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la direccion donde reside %s\n", p.nombre);
    gets(p.direccion); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento de %s\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%i", &p.fechaDeNacimiento); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el sexo de %s (M/F)\n", p.nombre);
    scanf("%c", &p.sexo); fflush(stdin);
    p.misVehiculos = NULL;
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

}

```
void registrarVehiculo(){
FILE *pFile;
FILE *pFileCopy;
personas p;
int encontrado = 0;
int x;
printf("Coloca el nro de Cedula de la persona que deseas buscar\n");
scanf("%i",&x);
pFile = fopen("Registro.txt", "r");
pFileCopy = fopen("Temp.txt", "w");
if(pFile==NULL){
    printf("Error");
    system("pause");
    return;
}else{
    fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pFile);
    while(!feof(pFile)){
        if(p.cedula == x){
            encontrado = 1;
            vehiculo *v = new vehiculo;
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese la placa del vehiculo (Maximo 8 caracteres)\n");
            gets(v->placa);fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese la marca del vehiculo\n");
            gets(v->marca);fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese el modelo del vehiculo\n");
            gets(v->modelo);fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese el año del vehiculo\n");
            scanf("%i", &v->year); fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese el Color del vehiculo\n");
            gets(v->color);fflush(stdin);
            v->sigVehiculo = NULL;
            if(p.misVehiculos == NULL){
                p.misVehiculos = v;
            }else{
                p.misVehiculos->sigVehiculo = p.misVehiculos;
                p.misVehiculos = v;
            }
            fwrite(&p, sizeof(p), 1, pFileCopy);
        }else{
            fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,pFileCopy);
        }
        fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pFile);
    }
}
fclose(pFile);
fclose(pFileCopy);
remove("Registro.txt");
rename("Temp.txt", "Registro.txt");
system("pause");
```

}

Comment: ¿La pregunta es sobre [tag:c] o sobre [tag:c++]?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es de C++ disculpa, se me escapo la etiqueta y no me di cuenta

Comment: @Trauma Si en parte responde a la pregunta, muchas gracias, pero si no se pueden guardar las direcciones de puntero, como haría en ese caso para poder guardarle la información de los vehículos a los usuario?, ya que cada uno de los usuarios pueden tener mas de un vehículo y la única forma que se me ocurría era con listas

Comment: @Anthonny Almacena las listas como si fueran vectores: guardas un indicador de cantidad, y los distintos vehículos uno a continuación de otro. Y al leer, pues recreas la lista original: por cada vehículo leído, reservas memoria y estableces los punteros.